# Will a 2x with a clutch RD be just as effective as a 1x with a clutch and narrow-wide chainring on an mtb?

Tags: mountain-bike

I am continuously dropping my chain on my enduro mtb rides (currently 2x). The rear derailleur that my bike is currently running is a deore non-clutch.

My chain will normally drop after riding rock gardens, jumps, and drop offs.

My friend  says that even if i get a clutch version of my current derailleur I will still drop my chain and that I should just convert to 1x. But a 1x conversion is more expensive and will lower my gear range. So I would like to know if a clutch 2x will have the same effect?

**Note:** My bike was new 2017 but has had hard use, the bike is a feul ex 5

Comment: How and where do you ride when you drop your chain? If you were to lose it on a smooth the road, your drivetrain isn't set up properly or worn. If you were to drop it after an enormous jump your requirements would be different.

Comment: Is the chain dropping in front or back?

Comment: Fuel Ex5 is speced as having a Deore M6000 - its already got a clutch. Are you sure your drive line is not just flogged out?

Comment: The correct chain length and properly maintained derailleur work miracles.

Answer (score 2):

It will help 2x, though 1x is going to hold chain better. I think you'll still see an improvement with a 2x setup due to added chain tension. When I upgraded the drivetrain on my full suspension to use a 10spd Shimano Deore clutch derailleur it didn't drop chain nearly as much if ever. Make sure you have your chain shortened to the appropriate length as that's one of the biggest factors causing chain slap and jumps is having a chain that's too long.

A 1x would likely work better if you switched to a narrow/wide chainring that prevents jumps though. I almost never drop a chain on the 1x setup with a race face narrow wide ring. The front chainring does a lot to stop the chain from slipping off due to the tooth profiles that really keep the chain engaged. I'm running a cheaper 10 speed setup on my hardtail with a sunrace 11-42 casette with a 10spd sram x-9 clutch derailleur and it works very well and was a cheap upgrade vs a whole new 11spd.

Answer (score 2):

Its not as simple as that. The difference between 1x with narrow wide and and 2x is both should not be dropping chains, ever.  Most people I know who fixed problems by going to 1x said something like "My new 1x is a vast a improvement over my x years old worn out drive drive line, ho ra for 1x  hail the 1x....."  (Followed no longer after by something along the lines of  "Shut up about the 1x already"). These people also largely forgot they when their bike was new they never had issues.

Upgrading to 1x means a completely new drive line so of course it will work. Upgrading just the rear derailleur means just a new rear derailleur, so it might not work depending on the state of the drive line, especially the chain rings.

If you 2x is dropping chains, something is not setup ideally - worn components, adjustments or bad chain line.  Upgrading to 1x will fix the worn components, but is most likely to make the chain-line worse unless you take great care or the BB has been changed on your existing setup.

IMHO provided you chain rings are in good condition, an XT clutch with new chain (and cassette if needed) will outperform you current setup of clutchless Deore.  If you need new chain-rings, a 1x would cost a bit more, but would be a better way to go.  The question you need to look at is cost - you could upgrade a few components to say XT level and keep the 2x, or deore level on 1x for similar money - which is the better drive line.

Comment: What will the difference be with XT?? (other than clutch obviously)

Comment: Just that XT is a better quality, and often available at same price as Deore.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to a clutch rear derailleur will help retain the chain. It's hard to say whether a 1x drivetrain would work better. Don't forget that with your 2x you have the front derailleur helping to keep the chain on the rings.